# Converting hour, minutes columns in dataframe to time format

Tags: r, type-conversion, time-format, datetime-conversion

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns including minutes and hours.
I want to convert these columns (namely minutes and column) to time format. Given the data in `drame`:

```
Score Hour Min
10    10    56
23    17    01
```

I would like to get:

```
Score Time
10    10:56:00
23    17:01:00
```

Comment: Which of the alternatives of my question below did you choose? Might be interesting for people who read this question later.

Comment: i used ISOdatetime but you need to specify year,month and date

Comment: And you just gave them arbitrary values I assume...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `ISOdatetime` to convert the numbers in the `hour` and `min` to a `POSIXct` object. However, a POSIXct object is only defined when it also includes a year, month and day.  So depending on your needs to can do several things:

- If you need a real time object which is correctly printed in graphs for example and can be used in arithmetic (addition, subtraction), you need to use `ISOdatetime`. `ISOdatetime` returns a so called `POSIXct` object, which is an R object which represents time. Then in `ISOdatetime` you just use fixed values for `year`, `month`, and `day`. This ofcourse only works if your dataset does not span multiple years.
- If you just need a character column `Time`, you can convert the `POSIXct` output to string using `strftime`. By setting the `format` argument to `"%H:%M:00"`. In this case however, you could also use `sprintf` to create the new character column without converting to `POSIXct`: `sprintf("%s:%s:00", drame$Hour, drame$Min)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **paste()** function to merge the two column data into a char and then use strptime() to convert to timestamp

```
x<-1:6  
##1 2 3 4 5 6
y<-8:13 
## 8 9 10 11 12 13

timestamp <- paste(x,":",y,":00",sep="")
timestamp
```

will result in

```
#1:8:00 2:9:00 3:10:00 4:11:00 5:12:00 6:13:00
```

If you prefer to convert this to timestamp object try using

```
strptime(mergedData,"%H:%M:%S") 
## uses current date by default
```

if you happen to have Date in another column use paste() to make a char formattted date and use below to get date time

```
##strptime(mergedData,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```